# Online mobile app builder in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to make windows phone 8 app.In which i want  to integrate online builder tool to create online mobile app and  download xap file on device.is there any API present for it ?

Answer (score 0):

That is not supported on Windows Phone. You can only sideload apps under certain conditions (such as having a dev account or I think a max of 2 apps).

Either way, you have to install it using MS tools, there are no API's available

Comment: can u explain  more about it ?

Comment: There's nothing to explain about it. Your idea is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. There are a few options for installing xap files.

- Install it in a developer unlocked device using the SDK tools
- Publish it as a beta, selected users can download it from the store
- Publish it the normal way (duh)
- Company deployment.

Have a look here: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/App_deployment_options_for_Windows_Phone

Comment: I understood your point.here is problem of installing app on device when we download it .leave installing concept. Can we simple create windows phone app using any online builder tool and send build file to his mailbox.

Comment: First of all: there is no way you can run a xap from your mailbox. That being said, you could investigate file or uri associations. With these associations you can launch your windows phone app when clicking a file or an uri. So, your online builder should produce something like, say, GreatApp.rozy or rozy:GreatApp and your windows phone app should know what to do. Have a look her http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx